# How can I set a variable to a value multiple times in one line?

Tags: python

I have this bit of code:

```
...

COMPANY = list(lines[30])
COMPANY = ''.join(COMPANY)
COMPANY = COMPANY.replace(",", "")
COMPANY = COMPANY.replace("\n", "")
COMPANY = COMPANY.split(" : ")
COMPANY[1] = COMPANY[1].lower()

...
```

And I am wondering if I can set `COMPANY` in one line instead of the above five lines.

Comment: why?  if it works it works and it's clear

Comment: Is it CVS parser? Do you need write your own?

Comment: Note that working code is much more important than concise code, though I applaud your desire to improve your coding style. Just don't feel you have to go back and rewrite _working_ code to improve the style - onwards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply chain the method calls:

```
COMPANY = ''.join(list(lines[30])).replace(",", "").replace("\n", "").split(" : ")
COMPANY[1] = COMPANY[1].lower()
```

If you don't like how it looks, you can split it up across multiple lines:

```
COMPANY = ''.join(list(lines[30]))              \
            .replace(",", "").replace("\n", "") \
            .split(" : ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
COMPANY = ''.join(list(lines[30])).replace(",","").replace("\n","").split(" : ")
COMPANY[1] = CAMPANY.lower()
```